# Change names of stacked raster data in plot rasterVis package in R

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster, raster-graphics

I have the next code:

```
list_data <- list.files(pattern="*NDVI",full.names=T)
```

stack my data using:

```
data <- stack(list_data)
```

and the names of layers is:

```
> names(data) 
 [1] "Max_NDVI_2000" "Max_NDVI_2001" "Max_NDVI_2002"
 [4] "Max_NDVI_2003" "Max_NDVI_2004" "Max_NDVI_2005"
 [7] "Max_NDVI_2006" "Max_NDVI_2007" "Max_NDVI_2008"
[10] "Max_NDVI_2009" "Max_NDVI_2010" "Max_NDVI_2011"
```

**then, i need change names of layer: 2000, 2001, ......, 2011,**, I'm using

```
names(data) <- 2000:2011
```

but I get X2000, X2001 ...

```
> names(data)
 [1] "X2000" "X2001" "X2002"
 [4] "X2003" "X2004" "X2005"
 [7] "X2006" "X2007" "X2008"
[10] "X2009" "X2010" "X2011"
```

however, if I use a characters the output is correct:

```
> names(data) <- month.abb 
> names(data)
 [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug"
 [9] "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

How the class of month.abb is character then, then I change

```
names(data) <- as.character(2000:2011)
```

but the output does not change.

**then, how I can change the names of layer? **.

PD: I need change the name for plot my data using the **[rasterVis](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/)** package (levelplot function)

Comment: Read `?validNames` Valid names do not start with a number.

Comment: Thank you, I change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For changing the name of layers in plot you can use `names.attr`:

```
levelplot(data,par.settings=BuRdTheme(),names.attr=c(as.character(2000:2011)))
```

Comment: Thank you @rar, just add as.character(2000:2011).  solved this problem.